# Find out where was mouse clicked on CDialogBar

Tags: winapi, user-interface, mfc, mouseevent, coordinates

I have control, subclassed from CDialogBar, it has some buttons(like on toolbar). When I catch WM_LBUTTONDOWN in the CDialogBar class is it a simple way of getting know if mouse was clicked on one of the buttons that are on the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CDialogBar` class normally hosts regular windowed controls, so when a button is clicked there, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message is sent to this control window, not the dialog window class. So if you want to intercept those messages (if you really do), you need to either subclass the windows and handle their messages, or install a message hook.

You can also use `Spy++` tool to see what messages are effectively reaching your `CDialogBar` window of interest to see if handling them might be a solution to your challenge.

Comment: yes, I subclass from CDialogBar, them I catch WM_LBUTTONDOWN, but I want different behaviour when user click on the button that are on the control

Comment: If you subclass the controls (to be clear - no the dialog bar itself), you can definitely override their behavior as you receive the messages into your `WndProc` and it is in your power to either forward the messages or handle them yourself. It does even not matter much here that the buttons are hosted by the dialog bar - important is that by subclassing you intercept message handling.

Comment: yes, I know I can, and I do. You don't understand the question, it's because of my bad English :( I do catch the  WM_LBUTTONDOWN event and handle it. I overrided PreTranslateMessage. The question is how can I if user clicked on the one of the buttons that are in the control, or just in the surface of the control. Actually I want forward this message to CDialogBar::PreTranslateMessage if user clicked on the buttons, and do my only my code, without standard, if he clicked not on the button but just on the control surface

Comment: User clicks a button, WM_LBUTTONDOWN is sent, you see it in your subclassing handler, and you `SendMessage` (or `PostMessage` so that it reaches your `PreTranslateMessage` through message queue) it to your `CDialogBar`. According to you, you already have everything for this.

Comment: yes, i have this all.How can I detect if user clicked on the button, not just on the surface? Like on [this image](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/SharpUI/Images%5CToolbarMerging%20IMG1.jpg) imahine that is my control, how can I detect in my WM_LBUTTONDOWN handler that user clicked on one of this buttons?

Comment: In general it depends on the window (control) class. Most controls have HitTest sort of messages which let you query if given coordinates belong to specific control area. For example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I used OnToolHitTest, for now it suits me. Thnks for your help!